# Jquery animate() gets laggy on chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, performance, jquery-animate

Here's my first jquery script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sliding test</title>
        <style>

                    html {
                height: 100%;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }

            body{
                text-align: center;
                background: url('bg.png');
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                box-shadow: 0 0 900px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
            }

            #global_wrap {
                width: 1000px;
                margin: 30px auto 0;
            }

            .container {
                /*background: pink;*/
                height: 240px;
                width:  290px;
                overflow: hidden;
                border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
                border: 3px solid #EAEAEA;
                display: inline-block;

            }

            .slide_wrapper {
                height: 500px;
                width:290px;
                margin-left: 0px;
                padding-left: 0px;
                text-align: left;
                background: white;
                margin-top: 0;
            }



            li {
                color: grey;
                list-style: none outside none;
            }

            a {
                color: inherit;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            img {
                display: block;
            }


            h3 {
                background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #252525;
                color: white;
                font-family: sans-serif;
                margin: 0;
                padding-bottom: 12px;
                padding-top: 12px;
                text-align: center;
                width: 290px;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
&nbsp;
        <div id="global_wrap">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="slide_wrapper">
                    <a href="javascript:;">
                        <img src="visuel1.jpg" width="290" height="193">
                        <h3>Category 1</h3>
                    </a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="container">
                <div class="slide_wrapper">
                    <a href="javascript:;" >
                        <img src="visuel2.png" width="290" height="193">
                        <h3>Category 2</h3>
                    </a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="container">
                <div class="slide_wrapper">
                    <a href="javascript:;">
                        <img src="visuel3.jpg" width="290" height="193">
                        <h3>Category 3</h3>
                    </a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>


        <script>   
        //wrapper_click=false;


        $(".slide_wrapper a").click(function(){

                if($(this).hasClass('open'))
                {
                   // wrapper_click = false;
                    $(this).parent().animate({'margin-top': '0px'}, 'slow');
                    $(this).removeClass('open');
                }
                else
                {
                    //wrapper_click = true;
                    $(this).parent().animate({'margin-top': '-193px'}, 'slow');
                    $(this).addClass('open');
                }
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I dont't know why, but it works fine on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/svmK5/

It works fine on all browsers, excepted chrome, I don't understand why... I think I’ve made some errors in my code, which makes it laggy

Does someone haves an idea about what is wrong in script?

Comment: Scrolls up smoothly for me... (Chrome V26.0.1410)

Comment: works in chrome... :) :)...

Comment: chrome works, but boxes are jumping when clicking on them.
http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/3509/68425220.jpg

Comment: i dont understand why, my local version doesn't work, and the jsfiddle is now working fine....

Comment: @davor Thank you for your report, i get this error too yesterday, and now i fixed it by adding a `float:left` on the "jumping" elements :) - Thanks you to others too for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works fine in chrome here, you could choose to use toggle class for less coding:

```
// toggleClass( class, [duration] )

$(".slide_wrapper a").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('open','slow');
});
```

css:

```
.open { 
 'margin-top': '-193px'
}
```

also all links inside the `slide_wrapper` will execute the on click even, i would suggest:

```
<a class="toggler" href="javascript:;">
$(".toggler").click...
```

this fiddle might help: http://jsfiddle.net/svmK5/8/

to fix the layout bug i used:

```
.slide_wrapper {
   float: left 
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but it is still laggy with this (but there's really less coding)

Comment: i used your code, i don't understand why but there's no animation (it works on your jsfiddle), the class toggles, but doesn't slide... any idea?

Comment: you need jquery UI,  this alters the toggle class function

Comment: Thank you, it works, but it is still laggy, i really dont understand what is wrong! please, can you try to copy/paste in a file the code i gave on the question and try to find what is wrong in it?

Comment: thank you for your help Joel, i have made an other answer with the fix, but i still give you the accepted answer for your precious help! - Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I found what made the script laggy, it was due to this CSS property:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

i don't know why this made my script laggy, but when i remove it, my script works perfectly

thank you all for your help, and particulary joel harkes for your very usefull help!

Answer (score 0):

This works fine in Chrome 26.0.1410

```
img{ image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast; }
```